# How to pass token from one controller to another?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jwt, authorization, codeigniter-4

I made a controller "Login" to make token below and successfully, but I don't know how to catch that token for another controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use App\Models\UserModel;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class Login extends ResourceController
{
    /**
     * Return an array of resource objects, themselves in array format
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    use ResponseTrait;
    public function index()
    {
        helper(['form']);
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|valid_email',
            'password' => 'required|min_length[6]'
        ];
        if (!$this->Validate($rules)) return $this->fail($this->validator->getErrors());
        $model = new UserModel();
        $user = $model->where("email", $this->request->getVar('email'))->first();
        if (!$user) return $this->failNotFound('Email Tidak Ditemukan');

        $verify = password_verify($this->request->getVar('password'), $user['password']);
        if (!$verify) return $this->fail('wrong Password');

        $key = getenv('TOKEN_SECRET');
        $payload = [
            // issue at : kapan token dibuat
            'iat' => 1356999524,
            // non before : kapan expired
            'nbf' => 1357000000,
            'uid' => $user['id'],
            'email' => $user['email'],
        ];
        $token = JWT::encode($payload, $key, 'HS256');
        return $this->respond($token);

        // return redirect()->to(base_url('/me', $token));
    }
}
```

I expect to know how the way to passing token from one controller to another

Answer (score 0):

The token can't be passed to a different controller. Instead, the client (I'm assuming you're working in a API) should send the token as a parameter or as a header. The most common cases use [Bearer Tokens](https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/what-is-bearer-token-and-how-it-works/)

Comment: can you give that reference or something else that i can learn how to send the token as a parameter or as a heder like you said,, (i'm don't know actually if that called as API)

Comment: @TommiAndrean I think you have the wrong approach with whatever you're coding. What are the requeriments of your software?

Comment: no, i have no requeriment.. i have a new task to make application, a simple application but that application should integrate with another application. i don't know where i start cause i''ve no experience in these case. so i  tried many ways including youtube tutorial and I don't know that it's right or wrong. would you like to telling me where to start and how ?